# Error in the Installation of caret library

Tags: r, package, r-caret

In running caret library I have this error :

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
library(caret)
```

```
error reading the fileError: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in readRDS(nsInfoFilePath):
 error reading from connection
```

Could you help me how to solve it?

Comment: Please include the code that generated the error.

Comment: Have you ever installed tha package named "caret"?

Comment: install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)

library(caret)

Comment: Already tried just `install.packages('caret')`?

Comment: Yes I did this.